# SQL Developer not failing on stored procedure error

Tags: oracle, jdbc, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I have a stored procedure that has a query inside it

```
v_sql : = 'select col1 from table1 where col2 = ' || inputArg1;
execute immediate v_sql into tempCol;
```

When the stored procedure is invoked through jdbc calls, it fails with error ORA-01403: no data found, when the above query returns 0 records.

However, when I execute the same stored procedure from either sqldeveloper or sqlplus, the same error is not showing up. Is there any setting (sqldeveloper) or argument (sqlplus) that I can pass to show such errors?

Comment: Both client throw an exception, unless you're suppressing it with a `when others` catch. How are you executing it? Are you sure you're calling the same procedure - in the same schema - and accessing the same table all the time?

Answer (score 1):

If this code is what you really execute (apart from modified table and column names), then you don't need dynamic SQL as there's nothing dynamic here. It is equal to

```
select col1 
  into tempCol
  from table1
  where col2 = inputArg1;
```

---

You asked

> Is there any setting (sqldeveloper) or argument (sqlplus) that I can pass to show such errors?

If that means that you want to make the procedure fail with `ORA-01403` (`no_data_found`), it's easy - pass value that doesn't exist in `col2` column. For example (based on Scott's sample schema):

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (inputArg1 in number) is
  2    tempCol number;
  3  begin
  4    select sal
  5      into tempCol
  6      from emp
  7      where empno = inputArg1;
  8  end;
  9  /

Procedure created.
```

Pass `empno` that exists (it is *Smith*):

```
SQL> exec p_test(7369);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Pass invalid `empno`:

```
SQL> exec p_test(-1);
BEGIN p_test(-1); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.P_TEST", line 4----
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL>
```

---

Finally: as procedure works fine in SQL Developer but not through JDBC, did you

- connect to the same user in the same database (you should have, otherwise you can't expect it to produce the same result) (as Alex commented)
- if you've just created `table1` table and/or inserted rows into it, did you **commit**? If not, only your current session sees those rows. JDBC is "another" session and can't see anything until you commit.

Comment: "It is equal to" - Unless you pass a SQL injection as a value. In case it needs to be dynamic, it should use bind variables: `execute immediate v_sql into tempCol using inputArg1`

Comment: I have to build the query dynamically, so I am building it in the way mentioned in the original post. I kept it simple for posting here.

When I call the stored procedure using call instead of exec (sqldeveloper or sqlplus), the error doesn't show up.